# Community ed: sell some products, leave other products as "enquire now"

Tags: code

I am not very experienced in Magento. A client currently has all their products with an "enquire now" button, instead of "add to cart", which opens a model window with a form requesting their contact details.

The "enquire now" functionality is custom code inside `app\design\frontend\default\modern\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`.

They now want to sell *some* of their products in the traditional way, and leave the rest as "enquire now".

Can I serve the custom "enquire now" code to most products, and serve the default "add to cart" code to other products?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, its possible, but you will need to share the code you have right now in view.phtml file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Additional attribute boolean  "Sell-able" or anything and get the value on that attribute on product view page and add a condition that is Sell-able = 0 then show enquire now else show "Add to cart '

Comment: Hi Vishwas. Can you provide some sample code please? I am not a developer, but a designer.